# Continuous string replacement causes invalid read in C

Tags: c, string, loops

I am trying to implement `replace` function in C.

I have `replace_str(char *str, char *sub, char *replacement)` function that returns `char *` to the modified string.

Here are the functions:

```
#define ALLOC(size, type) (type *) calloc(size, sizeof(type))
#define REALLOC(ptr, new_size, type) (type *) realloc(ptr, new_size * sizeof(type))

/**
 * Replaces all occurrences of given substring in string with given replacement.
 * @param str A dynamically allocated string that will be modified.
 * @param sub Old substring to be replaced.
 * @param replacement New substring.
 * @return The modified string.
 */
char *replace_str(char *str, char *sub, char *replacement) {
    unsigned long len_sub = strlen(sub);
    unsigned long len_rep = strlen(replacement);

    if (len_sub != len_rep) {
        unsigned long new_len = strlen(str) + (len_rep - len_sub) * count_substring(str, sub) + 1;
        str = REALLOC(str, new_len, char);
    }

    char *ptr = strstr(str, sub);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        char *str_tail = ptr + len_sub;
        char *temp_tail = ALLOC(strlen(str_tail) + 1, char);
        strcpy(temp_tail, str_tail);
        strcpy(ptr, replacement);
        strcat(str, temp_tail);
        free(temp_tail);
        ptr = strstr(ptr + len_rep, sub);
    }

    return str;
}

/* Counts number of non-overlapping times given substring mentioned in string. */
unsigned int count_substring(char *str, char *sub) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned long sub_len = strlen(sub);

    while (*str != '\0') {
        if (strncmp(str++, sub, sub_len) != false)
            continue;
        str += sub_len - 1;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

It works well, but when I have something like this:

```
char *a = ALLOC(11, char);
strcpy(a, "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

while (CONTAINS(a, "\n\n")) {
    a = replace_str(a, "\n\n", "\n");
}

free(a);
```

Valgrind complains that there are invalid reads:

```
==896== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==896== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==896== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==896== Command: /mnt/d/archive/education/hu/assignments/fall2019/assignment1/cmake-build-debug/matrixman ../inputs/arrays ../inputs/IO/commands1.txt output1.txt
==896==
==896== Invalid read of size 1
==896==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091F2: replace_str (strutils.h:140)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==  Address 0x522d096 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==896==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091B7: replace_str (strutils.h:134)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Addr1
   fun:strlen
   fun:replace_str
   fun:main
}
==896== Invalid read of size 1
==896==    at 0x4C32E03: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x10921A: replace_str (strutils.h:141)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==  Address 0x522d096 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==896==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091B7: replace_str (strutils.h:134)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Addr1
   fun:strcpy
   fun:replace_str
   fun:main
}
==896== Invalid read of size 1
==896==    at 0x4C32CF2: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091F2: replace_str (strutils.h:140)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==  Address 0x522d272 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==896==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091B7: replace_str (strutils.h:134)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Addr1
   fun:strlen
   fun:replace_str
   fun:main
}
==896== Invalid read of size 1
==896==    at 0x4FB7950: __strcpy_ssse3 (strcpy-ssse3.S:32)
==896==    by 0x10921A: replace_str (strutils.h:141)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==  Address 0x522d272 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==896==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==896==    by 0x1091B7: replace_str (strutils.h:134)
==896==    by 0x109496: main (main.c:33)
==896==
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Addr1
   fun:__strcpy_ssse3
   fun:replace_str
   fun:main
}
==896==
==896== HEAP SUMMARY:
==896==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==896==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 34 bytes allocated
==896==
==896== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==896==
==896== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==896== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It also happens when I use `replace_str` in a recursive function.

How can I solve this issue? What am I not seeing?

Comment: You realloc the string to smaller size before processing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I use the `needle` term meaning the `sub` argument passed to `replace_str` function.

```
unsigned long new_len = strlen(str) + (len_rep - len_sub) * count_substring(str, sub) + 1;
str = REALLOC(str, new_len, char);
```

`len_rep` is `strlen("\n")` so it's `1`.
`len_sub` is `strlen("\n\n")` so it's `2`.

So `(len_rep - len_sub)` is `-1`, so it equals to:

```
unsigned long new_len = strlen(str) + (-1) * count_substring(str, sub) + 1;
```

Assuming `count_substring` does what is says it does, you `realloc` the string to smaller size before even accessing it, so you are invalidating all bytes that are after `new_len`. That means if the string is `"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"` and needle is `"\n\n"`, there are 5 such sequences, you just realloc the string to 6 bytes. So the resulting array is only `6` bytes of `\n` : `{'\n,'\n','\n','\n','\n','\n'}`. All the bytes after index 5 are invalid and accessing them is undefined behavior. Valgrind exactly errors you that you access bytes after allocated memory:

```
==896==  Address 0x522d096 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==896==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

What you should do, is if the replacement string is shorter then the needle, move the realloc after the loop. If the replacement is longer then the needle, do the realloc before the loop.

```
if (len_rep > len_sub) {
    // WE NEED MORE PLACE
    const size_t new_len = strlen(str) + (len_rep - len_sub) * count_substring(str, sub) + 1;
    str = REALLOC(str, new_len, char);
    if (str == NULL) abort();
}

while (strstr(str, needle)) {
    // your loop is here
}

if (len_rep < len_sub) {
    // WE NEED LESS PLACE
    const size_t new_len = strlen(str) + (len_rep - len_sub) * count_substring(str, sub) + 1;
    str = REALLOC(str, new_len, char);
    if (str == NULL) abort();
}
```

Notes:

- Remember to check for allocation errors.
- Object size and strings length is represented using `size_t` type.
- Your function works strange. There is little need to do `malloc` inside the `while`, you don't need a temporary string. Just `memove` the parts of the string you have to save. And `memcpy` needle inside the string where you need it. Just like `while (str = strstr(str, needle), str) { memmove( <move str forth or back depending if len_rep is greater or smaller or equal to len_sub> ); memcpy(str, needle, strlen(needle)); str += strlen(needle); }`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Before your detailed explanation and after seeing your comment, I came up with the same solution of shrinking the string after the loop, but I was wondering if there's more elegant solution than splitting the realloc operation. I guess there isn't for _this_ replace algorithm. 

Thanks again for such detailed explanation!